# How to add jQuery functionality in the backend of a module?

Tags: joomla-2.5, module, jquery, jform

I'm making a module where the user can select some manufacturers names from the backend and the names will be posted in the index with some nice css.

I want to ask if I can add some jquery in the backend page, to make it easier for user.
I want to make a text box where will count how many manufacturers the user selected ( max 30 )
and a list with every manufacturer currently selected.
I will post an image to make it even more clear:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a custom form field for this.

So firstly, change the type of the field in your XML like so:

```
<field name="brands" type="brands" label="Foreign Brands" />
```

Then in your XML, replace your `<fieldset>` with:

```
<fieldset addfieldpath="/modules/mod_mymodule/fields">
```

Then, create a new PHP file called **brands.php** in:

> modules/mod_mymodule/fields

```
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldBrands extends JFormField
{
    protected $type = 'brands';

    public function getInput()
    {
       $doc = JDocument::getDocument();
       $js = '
              jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                  // Your JS code
              });
       '; 
       $doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);

       $options = array(
           'A.Dominguez' => 'A.Dominguez',
           'A.Feretti'   => 'A.Feretti',
           // Add more here
       );

       $select = JHtml::_('select.genericlist', $options, $this->name, null, 'value', 'text', $this->value, $this->id);

       return $select;
    }
}
```

Comment: in the above custom form field you entered the code to post the dropdown list also ?? or it is only for the 2 jquery elements ?? also really nice answer gonna test it in 5 mins!

Comment: Yes, this code will also render the dropdown list. You simply need to add all your values to the `$options` array. I have added a comment `// Add more here` where you need to do this and also a comment where you can add your jQuery code ;)

Comment: I allready created the custom form field code for the dropdown list, so the jquery code HAVE to be in the same file right ? or i can create a new one with only jquery code? could it work then ?

Comment: Yes you can do that too. Make sure you import the js file properly using Joomla coding standards. I on my way to work now but can show you when I get there

Comment: I would really like to learn how to do that :D

Comment: Now that i rethink that, i need to use different custom fields , as the 2 new fields i want to add will be type="text"

Comment: I've shown you how to use custom fields allowing you to add your own JS code. If you have a different question, please create a new one.

Comment: "Make sure you import the js file properly using Joomla coding standards." i just wanted to know what are those joomla coding standards

Comment: `JHtml::_('script', JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_mymodule/path/file.js');`

Comment: i got stuck a bit. this is the code of the 2 custom fields (dropdownlist and the text box where the counter of selected options will be printed ) http://pastebin.com/WAngY0TT where i actually add the import command ?

Comment: add it inside the getOptions function

Comment: I must do something completly wrong. in the next file i include every single file that is used for the output.
http://pastebin.com/UjFS0dfb
Could you please take a look if u dont mind ?

Comment: Please write a [new question](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as this may be confusing for those who want to do the same thing. Your initial question has been answered and solved and this is something different

Comment: ok im gonna do a new one